# When a user pick a speaker name on a dropdown list only the speakers expertise will show in the next topic dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php

What i want to achieved is when a user pick or choose a speaker name on a dropdown list only the speaker expertise will show up in the next topic dropdown list. Ex. When He choose Ms. Cimatu the topic dropdown list must only show the topics that Ms. Cimatu is familiar like Motivational, Entertainment, Healtcare. And When the user choose Mr. Santos the topic dropdown list must only show the  topics that he know like Business, and Technology. Btw the speakers names and topics that is show on the dropdown list is from a database that i get using select query and mysqli_fetch_array. Please guys any suggestions and help is really appreciated.

I already try this solution but my problem in this code is when i add new speaker, when i select their name it will not show any topics.

```
    <?php
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                $selectspeakers = "SELECT * FROM speakers";
                $sp_result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectspeakers);

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT speaker_fullname FROM speakers");
                $storeArray = Array();
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                {
                    $storeArray[] =  $row['speaker_fullname'];      
                }

                $msCimatuTopics = "SELECT speaker_specialization1, speaker_specialization2, speaker_specialization3, speaker_specialization4, speaker_specialization5  FROM speakers WHERE speaker_fullname = '$storeArray[0]' ";
                $msCimatuTopics_result = mysqli_query($conn, $msCimatuTopics);

                $mrSantosTopics = "SELECT speaker_specialization1, speaker_specialization2, speaker_specialization3, speaker_specialization4, speaker_specialization5  FROM speakers WHERE speaker_fullname ='$storeArray[1]' ";
                $mrSantosTopics_result = mysqli_query($conn, $mrSantosTopics);  
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="speaker">Preferred Speaker:</label>
    <select name="speaker" class="form-control" id="speaker" style='text-transform:capitalize;'>
    <?php while($array = mysqli_fetch_array($sp_result)):;?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_fullname'];?>" <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_fullname'];?></option>
 <?php endwhile;?>
 </select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="msCimatuTopics" id="topicTitle" class="hidden">Topic:</label>
 <select name="topic" class="form-control  hidden" id="msCimatuTopics" style='text-transform:capitalize;' autofocus required="required">
                                        <?php $array = mysqli_fetch_array($msCimatuTopics_result);?>
                                        <option value = "" <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> >Please Select...</option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization1'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization1']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization1'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization2'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization2']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization2'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization3'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization3']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization3'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization4'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization4']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization4'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization5'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization5']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization5'];?></option>
                                    </select>

                                <select name="topic" class="form-control  hidden" id="mrSantosTopics" style='text-transform:capitalize;' autofocus required="required">
                                        <?php $array = mysqli_fetch_array($mrSantosTopics_result);?>
                                        <option value = "" <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> >Please Select...</option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization1'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization1']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization1'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization2'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization2']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization2'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization3'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization3']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization3'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization4'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization4']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization4'];?></option>
                                        <option value = "<?php echo $array['speaker_specialization5'];?>" <?php if ($_POST['topic'] == $array['speaker_specialization5']) echo 'selected="selected"';?> <?php if($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] == $array['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?> ><?php echo $array['speaker_specialization5'];?></option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
        </body>
        </html>

    <script>      
        $('#speaker').change(function(){
        var selected_item = $(this).val()
        if(selected_item == "Ms. Cimatu")
        {
            $('#msCimatuTopics').val("").removeClass('hidden')
            $('#topicTitle').val("").removeClass('hidden'); 
            $('#mrSantosTopics').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        }
        else if(selected_item == "Mr. Santos")
        {
            $('#mrSantosTopics').val("").removeClass('hidden')
            $('#topicTitle').val("").removeClass('hidden');
            $('#msCimatuTopics').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#msCimatuTopics').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
            $('#mrSantosTopics').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
            $('#topicTitle').val(selected_item).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
    </script>
```

this is the image of dropdown list
[image]
This is the image of the database data
[image]

Comment: please guys i really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some basic things you can look to improve with your implementation. The biggest is you don't need to keep querying the same table for different pieces of data. If you are okay with running the `SELECT *` on the `speakers` table then you can skip the rest of your queries.

The next task is to try and make your code less dependent on singular values. If you notice you are writing the same code for value 1, value 2, etc then try to think about how to abstract your code so that it can work for an unlimited number of values.

This is a very rough implementation based on your sample code implementing the items I've mentioned. I have no way of testing it so there may be some small errors you need to debug before it works for your purpose:

```
<?php

    // Based on your code and image these appear to be the fields in the speakers table:
    //  speaker_fullname
    //  speaker_image
    //  speaker_videolink
    //  speaker_specialization1
    //  speaker_specialization2
    //  speaker_specialization3
    //  speaker_specialization4
    //  speaker_specialization5

    // Make your connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Get speakers and all their data (you only need one query!)
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM speakers");

    // Store the speakers for later
    //  (You could maybe use this instead but depends on your PHP version:)
    //      -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php
    $speaker_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $speaker_array[] =  $row;      
    }         

    // Apparently you have session values? You don't start the session though?
    //  See: http://php.net/session_start
    $session_speaker_fullname = ( ! empty($_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"])) ? $_SESSION["selectedSpeaker"] : '';

?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="speaker">Preferred Speaker:</label>
            <select name="speaker" class="form-control" id="speaker" style='text-transform:capitalize;'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach($speaker_array as $row):;?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['speaker_fullname'];?>" 
                        <?php if($session_speaker_fullname == $row['speaker_fullname']) echo "selected";?>
                        ><?php echo $row['speaker_fullname'];?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="topic" id="topicTitle" class="hidden">Topic:</label>
            <select name="topic" class="form-control" id="topic" style='text-transform:capitalize;' autofocus required="required">
                <!-- this will get populated via JavaScript -->                        
            </select>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Let your data be used by JavaScript
            var speaker_array = <?php echo json_encode($speaker_array); ?>;

            // A function to update the topic select
            function update_topic_select_list() {

                // Clear the current topic list
                $('#topic').html('');

                // Only re-build the topic list if a speaker is selected
                if ($('#speaker option:selected').val() != '') {
                    var topic_array = Array();

                    // Find the correct speaker
                    for (var i = 0; i < speaker_array.length; i++) {

                        // The speaker name matches
                        if (speaker_array[i].speaker_name == $('#speaker option:selected').val())

                            // Add the values to the topic array
                            topic_array.push(speaker_array[i].speaker_specialization1);
                            topic_array.push(speaker_array[i].speaker_specialization2);
                            topic_array.push(speaker_array[i].speaker_specialization3);
                            topic_array.push(speaker_array[i].speaker_specialization4);
                            topic_array.push(speaker_array[i].speaker_specialization5);

                            // Stop the loop
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Update the topic list
                    for (var i = 0; i < topic_array.length; i++) {

                        // Don't add empty values
                        if (topic_array[i] != '') {
                            $('#topic').append('<option value="' + topic_array[i] + '">' + topic_array[i] + '</option>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Watch for changes to the speaker selection
            $('#speaker').change(function() {

                // Do you need to do anything else?

                // Call the update function
                update_topic_select_list();
            });

            // Force a change trigger after page load - in case you need that session value set?
            $('#speaker').trigger('change');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sir thank you for answering my question.. i really appreciate it. But when i try it i think there a error in the javascript it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" its the fourth curly bracket on top of  // Watch for changes to the speaker selection. Please sir help me.. its so frustrating without any one to ask, and tutorials to watch..

Comment: sir its working nowwww!! the problem is the curly braces and the speaker_name should be speaker_fullname. THANK YOU KIND SIR!! I hope god give you more blessings for helping people like us!!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use AJAX. In this way, when the user selects a speaker, Javascript will request the server the list of specializations for the selected speaker. For example:

```
<!-- This is your <select> of speakers -->
<select id="select-speaker">
    <?php echo($speaker_options); ?>
</select>

<!-- This is your <select> of specializations -->
<select id="select-specialization">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>

<!-- This is your JS code -->
<script>
    // When users select the speaker, #select-specialization gets updated
    $("#select-speaker").change(function (){
        var speaker = document.getElementById("select-speaker");
        GetSpecializations(speaker.value).then(function (data){
            document.getElementById("select-specialization").innerHTML = data;
        });
    });

    async function GetSpecializations(speaker){
        // Request the server via AJAX the list of specializations for that speaker
        var options = await AjaxPOST("page.php", speaker);
        // Returns something like "<option value='spec1'>Spec1</option>..."
        return options;
    }
</script>
```

This is just an idea. Here's a possible implementation of `AjaxPOST()`:

```
function AjaxPOST(url, speaker){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var params = {"sentFromAJAX" : "true", "speaker" : speaker};
        http.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
                resolve(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        http.open("POST", url, true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        http.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    });
}
```

[This is a basic AJAX tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) from W3C and [this is a useful article on async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) from MDN.

P.S.: I didn't test this code. But it should work.

P.P.S.: It's missing the PHP part of code. You have to handle AJAX requests sent from Javascript. Note that this code sends the params encoded in JSON, so in PHP you have to retrieve `$_POST` variable using something like: `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) ?: [];`.